# JS Variable in jQuery ajax data

Tags: jquery, javascript

jQuery:

```
function myajax(var){
  $.ajax({
    url : 'ajax.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'html',
    data: {
      if(undefined != var){ variable : var, }
      content : $("#myinput").val()
  }
}
```

However, when calling the above function, the console shows `Unexpected token (` for the line with the `if`. How can I do this successfully? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an if statement inside of an object! You can not do that.

Move the logic outside of the object.

```
function myajax(var) {

    var data = {
        content: $("#myinput").val()
    };
    if (undefined !== var) {
        data.variable = var;
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: data
    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually do the validation in "beforeSend"

```
function myajax(var){
  var requestData;
  $.ajax({
    url : 'ajax.php',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : 'html',
    data: requestData,
    beforeSend : function(xhr){

      requestData = $("#myinput").val();
  }
}
```

Something like this might solve your problem

Comment: what is `variable : var,` -1